# Makefile target dependency in variable

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I can't figure out how target dependencies works, here is what I wrote to execute a target for each file in my directory :

```
FILES= $(wildcard *.txt)

all: $(FILES)
    @echo $(FILES)

%.txt:
    @echo "Runned $@"
```

This only echo the lists of the files and doesn't enter %.txt target, I want it to execute the target %.txt for all .txt files present in the directory (no matter if they have changed)

Comment: Your `.txt` files exist already and do not depend on anything. They are all up-to-date and there is thus no reason for `make` to run their recipes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem is that any target name matching `%.txt` already exists and has no dependencies so `make` sees no reason to rebuild it.  If you really want the commands to be rerun every time the simplest way is probably to introduce a [phony target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets) as a dependency...

```
FILES= $(wildcard *.txt)

all: $(FILES)
    @echo $(FILES)

.PHONY: .FORCE
%.txt: .FORCE
    @echo "Runned $@"
```